# What is the proper and reliable way to get a newly created UV map via python?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

Since Blender currently adds a newly created UV map at the end of the UV Map list, I initially retrieved a newly created UV map like this:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()
uv_map = obj.data.uv_layers[-1]
```

But this seems maybe not so reliable because what if Blender suddenly changed to add the UV map to the beginning of the list or alphabetically sorted it. So I'm currently doing it like this which seems so much overhead just to get the newly created uv map. Is there another reliable way to get the newly created UV map?

```
def create_uv_map(obj):
    before_uv_map_names = [uv_map.name for uv_map in obj.data.uv_layers]
    bpy.ops.mesh.uv_texture_add()
    after_uv_map_names = [uv_map.name for uv_map in obj.data.uv_layers]
    new_uv_map_name = (set(after_uv_map_names) - set(before_uv_map_names)).pop()
    return obj.data.uv_layers.get(new_uv_map_name)

uv_map = create_uv_map(bpy.context.active_object)
```

Comment: oh nevermind i didnt realize i can do `uv_map = obj.data.uv_layers.new(name="NewUVMap")`